# How to export all policies in Group Policy Management Editor via powershell (or any other method actually)?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo

I have a requirement from the auditing department where they want a list of all the available policies in the GPME.
I can export each branch through "right click → export" from the GUI, but this only gives me a txt with the name and comment of that branch/folder, not recursively.

Ideally, I'd like to have each policy name, configuration state and help (description) in a txt, csv or other regular file.

If that's asking too much, I can do with all the policies and their branches.

For example:
`User Configuration;Policies;Administrative Templates;Shared Folders;Allow DFS roots to be published`. That for each and every policy.

I've been googleing a way to obtain this via Powershell assuming that there would be a cmdlet that retrieve that info, but all I found was related to GPOs already created. I just need all the posible configurations a GPO might use.

Comment: get-gpo or get-gporeport?

Comment: @js2010 no mate, that gives me the report of a specific GPO or the GPOs applied. I need all the possible policies that you can setup in a GPO. 
Like a "get-childitem .\ -recurse", but for the Group Policy Management Editor.
Thanks anyway :)